# The best way to export a set of n matrices

Tags: matrix, export

Suppose I have 20 Matrices: Mat[1], Mat[2],...,Mat[20]. What is the best way to export (and Import) this set of Matrices in a file? How can I do that? (may be any format, for example: csv). Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)? If CSV works, then that's probably a pretty good choice of a text only format that is widely interoperable. Otherwise you could consider perhaps the [HDF5 file format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html).

Comment: Yes, but how the command is constructed to consider a set and not only one matrix? If I Export and Import, how could be the commands?

Comment: If your only need is to re-import into Mathematica, you can use DumpSave to save the definitions in a .mx file. They can then be imported using Get  ( << ).

Comment: Are you looking for 20 separate files or a single file with all 20 matrices?

Comment: Just one file. Severral files is easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Export` to save the set of objects. Let's say we have ten 2x2 matrices inside `a`:

```
a=Table[{{i,0},{0,i}},{i,10}];
```

Make an exporting function `ef` and sequentaly apply it for elements of `a`:

```
SetDirectory["your path"];
ef=Export[ToString[#[[1,1]]]<>".dat",#]&
ef/@a
```

It will give you ten dat-files with 2x2 matrices.

Of course, the simpler way is to export `a` as one file:

```
Export["file.dat", a]
```

or

```
DumpSave["file.mx",a]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpfull. Very clever.